# Ruby on Rails Accessing attributes of record found using .last

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my asset index view, when it loops through each `Asset`, I want to show the most recent scene name.  I am using .last to pull out the most recent record.  When I .inspect what is returned, I can see the values.  The problem is, when I try to access one of the attributes of what is returned I get an undefined method.

So for instance if I do this:

```
<%= (asset.scene_assignments.where(asset_id: asset).order("created_at").last).scene_id %>
```

I get:

> NoMethodError in Assets#index undefined method `scene_id' for SceneAssignment:0x4bc2c28

But if I call `#inspect` instead of `#name`, I can see what is contained inside. So if I do this:

```
<%= (asset.scene_assignments.where(asset_id: asset).order("created_at").last).inspect %>
```

It prints this:

> SceneAssignment id: 4, scene_id: 3, asset_id: 1, arrival_time: nil, created_at: "2014-10-16 01:43:50", updated_at: "2014-10-16 01:43:50", location_id: 1, asset_role_id: 1

Why can't I access one of the attributes from what is returned?

In my asset index view, I have this:

```
<% @assets.each do |asset| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= asset.name %></td>
    <td>
      <%= (asset.scene_assignments.where(asset_id: asset).order("created_at").last).inspect %>
    </td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', asset %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_asset_path(asset) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', asset, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

My relationship between an asset and scene is set up like this:

```
class SceneAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :scene
  belongs_to :asset
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :asset_role
  belongs_to :incident

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :asset
end

class Scene < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :scene_assignments
  has_many :assets, :through => :scene_assignments
  belongs_to :incident
  belongs_to :scene_type

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :scene_assignments, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :scene_assignments
  has_many :scenes, :through => :scene_assignments
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is `.scene_id`, not `.last` that is causing your error. The result of `.where(…) is a collection of records, not a single record.

To fix that, you could say `asset.scene_assignments.where(asset_id: asset).order("created_at").last).first.scene_id` though that makes some fairly messy code just a little bit worse. :)